# Get the list of outdated Composer packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to get list of outdated packages that will be updated when I issue `composer update`. Does composer have such functionality? if no is there a way to do that (with or without composer?)

Answer (score 167, accepted):

**Update:**

Since [Composer v1.1 (May 2016)](https://github.com/composer/composer/releases/tag/1.1.0) the following commands are available:

- `composer outdated` shows you the list of outdated packages
- `composer show -l` returns the complete list of packages. packages in need of update are colored red. the (still) up-2-date ones are colored green.
- both commands accept the parameter `--direct` to show only direct dependencies in the listing

Referencing:

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3771

---

**Composer Plugins**

There are some Composer Plugins showing the list of outdated packages:

1. **composer-versions-check** - https://github.com/Soullivaneuh/composer-versions-check

   The Composer Plugin called "composer-versions-check" shows outdated packages from last major versions after using the update command. (Latest is ..)

   This plugin runs "update" first, then shows possible "upgrade" indications.

   A Composer `dry-run` isn't supported, [yet](https://github.com/Soullivaneuh/composer-versions-check/issues/24).

   [image: Composer-Version-Check-Plugin]
2. **vinkla/climb** - https://github.com/vinkla/climb

   Climb is a "Composer version manager tool" inspired by [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).

   It shows the outdates package version and indicates "upgrades" to latest versions.

Comment: "When you execute update the packages are installed"

Which packages do you refer here? Since `update` should update only packages I installed with `install`?

Comment: Yes, the packages defined in your composer.json file. First you install, then you can update several times, right? For instance, when you define a requirement of package-A with version `1.2.*` and run install or update - it will only fetch a version in the MINOR.PATCH_LEVEL version range. It will never grab the latest version (when this package-A has a version 2.0.0) or grab version 1.3, 1.4, etc. And then you will get the message that you are using an outdated package (not the latest version) and that the latest version is 2.0.0.

Comment: Now I want something that will check versions without doing actual update, some kind of dry check.

Comment: Maybe add this plugin and use `composer update --dry-run`.

Comment: `--dry-run` doesn't work so far see here: https://github.com/Soullivaneuh/composer-versions-check/issues/24

Comment: True, there is more work needed to get it working in dry-run mode. I found  another tool, which provides a list of outdated packages, but misses the update/upgrade functionality: https://github.com/vinkla/climb . I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: The command `composer show -o` lists only outdated libraries in use.

Answer (score 28):

Since version 1.1 of Composer there is the `composer outdated` command. With `composer outdated --direct` only your direct dependencies are taken into account.

Answer (score 11):

To complete @jens-a-koch response, get any dependency update:

```sh
composer outdated
```

or get only direct dependencies from your composer.json:

```sh
composer outdated -D
```

https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#outdated

> outdated
>
> The outdated command shows a list of installed packages that have
>   updates available, including their current and latest versions. This
>   is basically an alias for composer show -lo.
>
> The color coding is as such:
>
> - green (=): Dependency is in the latest version and is up to date.
> - yellow (~): Dependency has a new version available that includes backwards compatibility breaks according to semver, so upgrade when you can but it may involve work.
> - red (!): Dependency has a new version that is semver-compatible and you should upgrade it.
>
> Options
>
> - --all (-a): Show all packages, not just outdated (alias for composer show -l).
> - --direct (-D): Restricts the list of packages to your direct dependencies.
> - --strict: Returns non-zero exit code if any package is outdated.
> - --minor-only (-m): Only shows packages that have minor SemVer-compatible updates.
> - --format (-f): Lets you pick between text (default) or json output format.